# iPad - Draw Rotated Text using drawRect method in iPad

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-graphics, ios-simulator, cgaffinetransform

I am working on an ipad application in which I am trying to render an image with multiple text label. I am drawing the text on context using drawRect method.
I want an output something like shown in figure below:

http://tinyurl.com/bypf9kq

but I am getting an output like shown in figure below

http://tinyurl.com/acz4l9y

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please post some of your code in order to receive help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CGFloat DegreesToRadiansText(CGFloat degrees) {return degrees * M_PI / 180;};
CGContextSelectFont (context, "Helvetica", 60, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetCharacterSpacing (context, 10);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (context, kCGTextFill);
CGContextSetGrayFillColor(context, 0.0, 1.0);
CGAffineTransform myTextTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.f, -1.f ),(DegreesToRadiansText (-90));
CGContextSetTextMatrix (context, myTextTransform);
CGContextShowTextAtPoint (context, 100, 200, "Quartz 2D", 9);
```

Taken from [Here.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1664196?start=0&tstart=0)

Basically you set the text matrix to a custom transform matrix and then draw.  You may want to do a `CGContextSave` prior to transforming and a `CGContextRestore` when finished drawing the text.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked like charm, you saved my day. Thanks once again.

Comment: I get an error on the first line, can you provide more context to that line of code please?